# Writing to output without buffering in Julia

Tags: output, buffer, julia, flush

What is the way to print data on standard output without buffering?
println buffers data and writes them all together.

Equivalently a command to empty the print buffer would be useful.

Comment: It would be great if there was an option (command line flag?) to disable output buffering entirely, without having to add flush commands through an entire program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`flush` is the command to empty the print buffer for a given stream: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.flush

Comment: Unfortunately, link is dead.

Comment: This one works:
https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/io-network/#Base.flush

Comment: The link is dead again

Comment: This gives an example https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-flush-stdout/10146

Comment: Current docs link is: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.flush